# Difference between Class and Typename for C++ template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am slightly confused about c++ template.

Considering the template below

```
template<class TYPE>
void function(TYPE data)
```

and

```
template<typename TYPE>
void function(TYPE data)
```

My confusion is exactly what is the difference between typename and class  used as variable identify or type.

Comment: You can see in a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Type_template_parameter) that there's no difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For designating (type) template parameters, the two are exactly identical, just like `int`/`signed int`, or `&&`/`and`: `template <typename>`/`template <class>`.

A curious restriction applies to template template parameters up to C++14:

```
template <template <typename> class Tmpl> struct Foo;
//                            ^^^^^
```

Here only the keyword `class` is allowed to designate the template template parameter.

After C++14, you will be able to consistently use either `class` or `typename` everywhere:

```
template <template <typename> typename Tmpl> struct Foo;
```

Comment: Hence, so they choice to use either is always the programmers I suppose. Or does either one has some benefits i.e in Memory management or something deeper level?

Comment: @kcc__ "exactly identical" means "exactly identical".

Comment: @kcc There is one important difference: `class` is 3 letters shorter than `typename`.

Comment: @Yakk did I just create any JOKE here. If you cant answer please dont comment

Comment: @kcc__ I am not making a joke.  The fact that `class` is 3 letters shorter than `typename` in the declaration of types in a `template` is the most important difference between using the two.  A 37% decrease in boilerplate is important!

Comment: Is than any way important in programming. Accordingly than using variable names of single character is more evective than using camelcase style. Anyways thanks for your advise... :D

Comment: @kcc__ yes, if the two are "equally clear", using `MyNameIsALongVariableNameThatMeansTheFirstLetterOfTheAlphabet` is significantly worse than `A` as a variable name.  And as `class` and `typename` have the same meaning when declaring a type within a template argument, the length difference reduces the amount of "noise" on the line with `class`.  It isn't a huge difference, but it is the largest difference.

Answer (score 3):

There IS a difference between the two.

`class` defines a class, so if you want to define a templated class as a template parameter, you have to use that.

For example you can define a template that receives a templated class type:

```
template <class A>
class Blah
{

};

template <template <class , class> class T, class A, class B>
class Blah<T<A,B>>
{

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Blah<std::vector<int>> a;

    return 0;
}
```

You can't declare a templated class like that with `typename`.

Also `typename` is used as a keyword to access **[dependent template names](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)**.

Comment: This answer will very shortly be wrong: in the current iteration of standardization, `temlate< template<class,class>typename Z, class A, class B>` will be legal and have the same meaning as `template<template<class,class>class Z, class A, class B>`.  The sentence "`class` defines a class, so if you want to define..." has a true conclusion, a true premise, but the two are only vaguely connected.   ;)  It is true the introduction of non-class templates was the reason why the `class` keyword requirement there was dropped, but those didn't happen at the same time!